# Facebook tagging user on a photo in a Page Gallery via SDK and Graph is possible?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to tag a user (having its userid), with a Graph request made to a picture just uploaded to a Page Gallery.

Permissions I use in the app are:
@"read_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_stream", @"manage_pages",@"photo_upload",@"user_photos" and with a access_token to the session got from page_it?fields=access_token item (that works for picture upload in gallery).

And I use them to upload the photo to a Gallery on a Fan Page successfully.

When I try to tag the user with a graph request in the form:

POST to picture_id/tags with param: "to"->userid
I get only facebookErrDomain error 10000 as if permissions are not right.

From API Documentation seems that only user_photos and publish_stream are required and no mention to page-galleries photo is made.

I'm quite clueless about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You need to collect the page's specific token by placing a call to /me/accounts. And then tag the photo using page's access token. Once you get that, you can tag the photo using it's Graph Object Id and user id whom you are tagging.

```
if (accessToken) {
    var data = {
        "access_token": accessToken,
        to:userId,
        x:x,
        y:y
    }
    FB.api("/" + photoId+"/tags/"+userId , 'post', data, function(response) {
        //here is the response
    });
}
```

Hope it helps. The key is the access token that is specific to that page :)